# Which web-based version control system should we use with .net and visual Studio

Tags: version-control

We are about to begin a project where we will be working with a few developers all around the country (and possibly world). I'm looking for a good source control solution that is cloud-based where the developers can check in and check out source files.

If it matters, the project itself is .Net and the developers are working in Visual Studio.

Also we have tried tortous-SVN and the like, we are looking for a different, web based solution. Anyone know of anything i can take a look at?

Thanks

Comment: This may be considered a duplicate of, eg, [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35465/easy-simple-online-source-control) or [that one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29736/what-open-source-hosting-service-should-i-use). Can you tell us what aspect of your problem is not solved by the corresponding answers?

Comment: Don't accept **signle** answer too fast. Nobody answered you yet really

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about github.com?  It's quite popular and well thought-of.

Comment: +1 for git/github as they are a dvcs (**Distributed** version control sytem)as opposed to tools like svn, a simpler version control system will all commits being to the remote.

Comment: -1 for Git advertising in any ass. Distributed features not asked explicitly, with VCS-hosting and described workflow CVCSes fit nicely

Answer (score 0):

You haven't any reasons (mentioned) to use exactly **cloud-based solution**. And also doesn't mention which VCS you can (have|planning) to use

For just web-frontend to *VCS-of-choice* your have wide selection of pure VCS-hostings (free or not) or PM|ALM tools

I can't see real question here, at least while requirements are not defined more strictly and deeply